# Java Timer usage with JButtons

Tags: java, swing, timer, jbutton

I have problem that I don't understand, how to correctly use the Java timer with JButton.

**The idea of what I need -**
When I click on JButton with text "0" then starts the timer counting from two seconds till zero.
When button is released program checks the situation:
if timer now is 0 then it shows in JTextField sign "+", else it shows "0".

Here is my code of program. Can someone please add the things that I need to make the program work like the idea I want?

```
public class DialPanel extends JPanel {
    private MainFrame frame;

    public DialPanel(MainFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;

        this.setLocation(0, 90);
        this.setSize(300, 290);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(color);

        this.initContent();
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private JButton btnNumZero;
    private JTextField txfNumber;

    private void initContent() {
        txfNumber = new JTextField();
        this.add(txfNumber);
        txfNumber.setSize(190, 30);
        txfNumber.setLocation(30, 0);
        txfNumber.setFocusable(false);
        txfNumber.addActionListener(controller);

        btnNumZero = new JButton();
        this.add(btnNumZero);
        btnNumZero.setText("0");
        btnNumZero.setFocusable(false);
        btnNumZero.setSize(30, 30);
        btnNumZero.setLocation(10, 10);
        btnNumZero.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                //Start someTimer countdown from two seconds
            }
        });
        btnNumZero.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                //Stop someTimer
                //if someTimer == 0 seconds then do this line:
                txfNumber.setText("+");
                //else do this line:
                txfNumber.setText("0");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Excuse me if there is some unnecessary error with code. I deleted and changed a lot of things from the real one code so that this could be more understandable and clear for reading.

Comment: We actually need to see the way you used the Timer, i mean is it the saint one or the devil one. (saint and devil is defined in perspective of Swing ;))

Comment: I tried to look something on internet how to add Timers to JButton but I didn't understand. Nothing works. That's why I asked here if someone can add any type of timer that would make program work like I need.

Comment: To work with Swing. have a look into [Swing Timer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: That's the one that I looked but I didn't understand how to implement it in my program so it could work..

Comment: Nobody answers... Is it so hard to implement some timer?

Comment: this is not that it is hard. This is that we need you understand and try something on it first. At least you need to show us how actually have you tried!

Comment: I tried to implement some timer from examples but all the time It came on errors and errors. I even don't understand from where people get that method timer.start(). I have absolutely no idea, how to do this. Can You please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a Timer, you may want to just make use of `System.currentTimeMillis()`. The `Timer` may not be a timer in the sense you are looking for, as a stopwatch type object.

You could do something like this

```
   long startTime;
   long endTime;

   btnNumZero.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    });
    btnNumZero.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long difference = endTime - startTime;

            if (difference > 2000)
                txfNumber.setText("+");
            else
                txfNumber.setText("0");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I feel stupid that I didn't realized way of problem solving like this by myself. Mind confused ^_^ Thanks, it worked! ;)